# Python module logging with eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, logging, module, package

I am trying to get logging going across a couple of different modules using     `logging.config.fileConfig()` My directory looks something like this:

```
> Package
   > Source
       __init__.py
       SomeSource.py
   > Test
       __init__.py
       SomeTests.py
   __init__.py
```

Inside in `Package.__init__.py` I have the following:

```
directory = 'C:/User/Me/workspace/Package/'
logFile = 'logger.conf'
logging.config.fileConfig(directory+logFile)
log = logging.getLogger('Package')
log.info('Logging initialized.')

import Test
```

Inside in `Package.Test.__init__.py` I have

```
log = logging.getLogger('Package.Test')
log.info('Test module started')
```

So the expected output for this is something like:

```
Logging initialized.
Test Module started.
```

I can get this to run and log correctly while using eclipse using Ctrl+F11. However, calling it from the interpreter results in nothing at all:

```
>>> import Package
```

The log file remains empty. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python module logging with eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949159/python-module-logging-with-eclipse)

Comment: Why post the exact same question three times?

Comment: Snap, new to the site. Is there some way I can delete some of these? Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Python directory. It is probably in there.